# How to fix: Permission Denied, runtime error 70, FSO filescripting, Computer Issue

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a code using to backup the current active Access Database using VBA.
but it works only on my laptop, not on my computer at work.
both of them is Win 10, Same office version, Security Permission is also the same settings, what can be the problem? the difference?

Please see the provided code here:

```
Sub backup()

Dim FSO As Object

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

FSO.CopyFile Application.CurrentProject.FullName, _
Left(Application.CurrentProject.FullName, _
Len(Application.CurrentProject.FullName) - 6) & "_Backup.accdb"

End Sub
```

Comment: It is not a coding problem, it is related to your computer(s) to which we have no access.

Comment: I know it's not a coding issue, it works on my laptop. the question is: It's my own computer, all settings the same as my laptop. why i don't have access?? and where can i change this?

Comment: permission denied is a security problem, if you are on a network there should be a limit to your access to that folder. Try to browse to the destination folder manually and create a text file and try to delete it and see how far you can go.

Comment: The file i'm using is a Local File on my desktop!

Comment: _It's my own computer, all settings the same as my laptop. why i don't have access??_ Becasue it is not so; at least one setting/security/account/permission is different.

Comment: I tried also to copy the file myself with windows explorer, and on my laptop it works, on my computer i got this message: "This Action can't be completed, because the file is open in microsoft access. close the file and try again"
So, looks like the permission problem is that the file is open. nothing else.
the question is why i can't copy a ms-access opened file on my computer.

i found out more, on my laptop i see a "laccdb" file when my file is open, but on my computer is missing the "laccdb" file.

i would changed the topic to: "IS POSSIBLE TO COPY AN ACCESS FILE WHILE IT'S OPEN?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution after a lot of testing and troublesooting
The solution is the setting of "Deafult open mode" in access. i changed from "Exclusive" to "Shared" and it works.